# Checking Google license from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

Would it be possible and worthwhile?

I mean, it could potentially give much needed extra protection for apps that already use native code for some important tasks. These apps could include license check in these tasks, so that crackers could not just remove the native function call from the byte code or if they did, the app would not just work. Or is there some caveats that I'm not seeing?

Would the JNI be the only way to do this? I've used it before, but it seems quite cumbersome to use it for something like this.

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see your point. Why wouldn't the program work if they removed the native code call or native code method? The program would still function even if that native method was never called.

Comment: Not if the function does something important that the app cannot do without. Let's say that the app needs to do some calculations in the native code. When this calculation function is called it would first check the license (if needed) and then perform the calculation. If the license check is not succesful, it would just return and not perform the calculations and the app would fail.

Comment: That still doesn't stop people from deleting the license check even if it would be better.

Comment: Yes of course, but it would be much more difficult.

Comment: Nope. I'm quite baffled that this has been overlooked by Google. I know that there is native API for IPC that could be potentially used for this, but afaik it isn't public. Why? I dunno.

Comment: still not possible? any workarounds / other securing ideas?